# Cutoff frequencies of active this filter?

Tags: operational-amplifier, capacitor, filter, active-filter, passive-filter

How can I calculate precisely the roll-off frequencies of this configuration? The passband seem to be between 3.1Hz to 78.1Hz. I tried using the equations for the inverting active bandpass filter but they gave different results. I can't seem to be able to get these values with any combination of values, what am I missing out?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The passband seem to be between 3.1Hz to 78.1Hz

[image]

C4 and R6 define the LF cut-off and that equals 3.38 Hz

C3 and R4 define the HF cut-off and that equals 72.34 Hz

If you are measuring a difference in your sim then this is likely due to imperfections in the LM324 i.e. non-infinite input resistance. There will also be a slight effect due to C6 and R10.

Comment: That's what I thought, just a sanity check, thank you :)